# How to compare content of one text file with first line of another and use in if statement in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, cmp

I'm currently doing the following in a shell script to compare the output of a process (`latest_sg.json`) with the previous output (`latest_sg_prev.json`) and if they are the same, do nothing.

```
 cmp -s latest_sg.json latest_sg_prev.json >/dev/null 
    if [ $? -ne 1 ]; then
     sed -n '1p' latest_sg.json | sed -i '1r /dev/stdin' sg_monitor.json && sed -i '2s/$/,/' sg_monitor.json;

    else
      echo  same
    fi
```

If they are different, the script should copy the new content to a larger file (`sg_monitor.json`) at the end of the first line, then append a comma on to the end of that line.

The input file contains value pairs:

`{"value":"100","entry":"100","type":"sgv"}`

The output file looks like this when everything is normal:

```
[
{"value":"100","entry":"100","type":"sgv"},
{"value":"100","entry":"100","type":"sgv"},
{"value":"100","entry":"100","type":"sgv"}
]
```

However, what I'm finding happening is that if the two input files are the same, an additional comma is appended to the 2nd line in the `sg_monitor.json` file as below:

```
[
{"value":"100","entry":"100","type":"sgv"},,
{"value":"100","entry":"100","type":"sgv"},
{"value":"100","entry":"100","type":"sgv"}
]
```

This then screws up the process that is parsing the output file.

I'd either like to stop this behaviour where the additional comma is added when `latest_sg.json` and `latest_sg_prev.json` are the same, and even better would be to check the content of `latest_sg.json` against the first line of `sg_monitor.json` and if it already exists, not take any action.

How would I do this?

Comment: **If** they are identical, the *then* part would not be executed and no comma would be added. Hence, they are not the same, so the problem boils down to find out where the files differ, when you **believe** they are the same. Instead of suppressing the output of `cmp`, let `cmp` tell you where the files differ.

Comment: As an aside, `cmd; if [ $? -eq 0 ]` is an antipattern. The sole purpose of `if` is to run a command and examine its exit code; the idiomatic replacement is simply `if cmd`.

Answer (score 0):

Two observation

1) You're statement `what I'm finding happening is that if the two input files are the same, an additional comma is appended to the 2nd line in the sg_monitor.json` contradicts with the code that you have given. If both file are equals,you're code will go in else statement and it should execute `echo  same`.

2) You are trying to add a `,` by finding character `S` on second line. I assume you want to add comma at end of line. So use `$` instead of `S`

Instead of using

`sed -i '2s/S/,/' sg_monitor.json`, try using

`sed -i '2s/$/,/' sg_monitor.json`

Or you can try something like

`sed -i '2s/}/&,/' sg_monitor.json` where `}` is the last character on line 2

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that you are running `echo same` if the 2 files are *not* equal. From the `cmp` Man page:

> Exit status is 0 if inputs are the same, 1 if different, 2 if trouble.

Change the if statement to be `$? -eq 1` instead of `$? -ne 1`. (Also, you can pass `--quiet` to `cmp` to suppress output instead of piping it to `/dev/null`)

I'm not quite sure what these commands are supposed to be doing, but the second command is adding a comma to the end of the 2nd line of `sg_monitor.json`:

```
sed -n '1p' latest_sg.json | sed -i '1r /dev/stdin' sg_monitor.json
sed -i '2s/$/,/' sg_monitor.json
```

Comment: Thanks - I think that explains my issue. I'm misusing the output of cmp. Will have to make a change. The 1st line you've shown is copying the first line of "latest_sg.json" to the end of the first line of "sg_monitor.json" so that I retain formatting and time series on the "sg_monitor" file.